# Complex integration $e^{1/z}$ over unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I know how to do this using the residue theorem, but I do not know how to integrate it term by term.

I wrote $e^{1/z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-in\theta}}{n!}$, and

$$
\int e^{1/z}dz = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-in\theta}}{n!}ie^{i\theta}d\theta = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{i}{n!}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{(1-n)i\theta}d\theta.
$$

Let $I = \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{(1-n)i\theta}d\theta$, $I = 0$ so the integral is $0$.

However, when I do the integral using the residue theorem, I got $2\pi i$. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define $$I_n = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{(1-n)i\theta}\,d\theta,$$ then $I_n = 0$ for 
 any integer $n\neq 1$; however, $I_1 = 2\pi.$

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I was so confused...